# Как сделать плавный изгиб - переход от красной части меню к чёрной

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg

[image: такое]

Это можно сделать используя CSS? Или придётся картинкой делать?

Comment: Поставил тебе плюс в тему т.к. там стоял минус 1 и я никогда не понимал, и не понимаю людей, которые вместо того чтобы помогать тому, кто учится, спрашивает, они гнобят и минусуют! Я считаю, что тех авторов, которые всем лепят минусы пора штрафовать за злоупотребление на этом форуме! Удачи тебе в учебе!

Comment: Поддерживаю! Никогда не понимал, почему лепят минусы, если вопрос по учебе

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самое простое (и, наверное, разумное) - вставить статичную картинку фоном, но ей нельзя будет управлять, зато ее можно будет просто растягивать.

С использованием `clip-path` все сложнее и грязнее – его нельзя адекватно растянуть, сам "шейп" надо кидать в html (основопологающий элемент управления вектором отложили в самый дальний ящик, `clip-path: path()` сейчас working draft, и поддерживается только в firefox).
Safari отнимает возможность импортить части svg, а с ней можно было-бы хранить все шейпы в отдельной свг по аналогии со стилями.

Вот моя чистенькая, как обычно рукописная реализация с svg/clip-path:

```css
nav {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 14px/20px Arial;
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 70px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
  position: relative;
}

nav li.active ~ li {
  background: transparent;
}

nav li.active:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  position: absolute;
  right: -79px; /* артефакты на ретине */
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
  clip-path: url(#navDivider);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li class="active">About</li>
  <li>Contacts</li>
</nav>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="navDivider" transform="scale(40)">
      <path d="M 0 0 C 1 0, 1 1, 2 1 S 1 1, 0 1"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: svg то адаптивный, а вот clip-path – нет. Очень сырое свойство которое на нет само  себя сводит. Ну и это единственный способ сделать маску + 2x 3x 4x + мизерный вес по сравнению с чем угодно.

Answer (score 11):

### Решение на чистом CSS

*Правда совсем небольшой дефект виден, но это уже если всматриваться. Думаю, что пользователи сайта этого как правило не делают :) Но зато есть градиент и вся задумка решена на 99,9%.*

**UPD** Улучшил ответ. Теперь дефект практически не заметен. А также учёл замечания @Alexandr_TT и @ArtemGorlachev и добавил ещё дополнительно адаптивный вариант. Адаптивность конечно получилась не совсем та, что хотелось, но постараюсь доработать.

```css
.nav {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav__left {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 49%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

.nav__right {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  height: 80px;
  width: 49%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black);
}

.transition {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
  width: 180px;
}

.transition__red {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black);
}

.transition__red:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0px 90px 0px 0px / 0px 100% 0px 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

.transition__black {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

.transition__black:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100% / 0 0 0 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black);
}

.transition__clear {
  position: absolute;
  left: -56px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

.transition__clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: -151px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0% 60% 0% 0%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

span {
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.nav__left span {
  float: left;
}

.nav__right span {
  float: right;
}

.block__left {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 49%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

.block__right {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  height: 80px;
  width: 49%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav__left"><span>А-ля Left</span></div>
  <div class="nav__right"><span>А-ля Right</span></div>
  <div class="transition">
    <div class="transition__black">
    </div>
    <div class="transition__red">
    </div>
    <div class="transition__clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block__left"></div>
<div class="block__right"></div>
```

### Адаптивный вариант:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 30vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav__left {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 30vh;
  width: 49%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

.nav__right {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 30vh;
  width: 49%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black);
}

.transition {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 30vh;
  width: 180px;
}

.transition__red {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 30vh;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black);
}

.transition__red:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 30vh;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0px 90px 0px 0px / 0px 100% 0px 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

.transition__black {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 30vh;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

.transition__black:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 30vh;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100% / 0 0 0 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black);
}

.transition__clear {
  position: absolute;
  left: -56px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

.transition__clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: -151px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 0% 60% 0% 0%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred);
}

span {
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.nav__left span {
  float: left;
}

.nav__right span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav__left"><span>А-ля Left</span></div>
  <div class="nav__right"><span>А-ля Right</span></div>
  <div class="transition">
    <div class="transition__black">
    </div>
    <div class="transition__red">
    </div>
    <div class="transition__clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а даже офигел ..на css \

Comment: @Sevastopol' можно почище и поадаптивней ваш вариант сделать, у меня в мозге ограничитель стоит на дом элементы только для дизайна, но тут можно красиво замутить)

Answer (score 10):

Вот, если угодно, на градиентах:

```css
.top, .bottom {
  height: 22.5px;
  --r: 30px;
  --g: radial-gradient(
          circle at calc(50% - calc(var(--o) * 50%)) 0, 
          var(--c1), 
          var(--c1) calc(50% - var(--r)), 
          #0000 calc(2px + calc(50% - var(--r)))),
       radial-gradient(
          circle at calc(50% - calc(calc(var(--o) * var(--r)))) calc(50% + calc(var(--o) * 80%)), 
          var(--c1), 
          var(--c1) calc(var(--r) - 1px), 
          var(--c2) calc(var(--r) + 1px));
}

.top {
  --c1: red;
  --c2: black;
  --o: 0.98;
  background: var(--g);
}

.bottom {
  --c1: black;
  --c2: red;
  --o: -0.98;
  background: var(--g);
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Вот так это делается!

Если требуются подробности - спрашивайте - поясню со скринами

Сделал меню и адаптировал его в codepen ... [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oNgmzyx)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  width: 480px;
  align-items: center;
  background: #b83d2e;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: ;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 170px;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">ссылка №1</a>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">ссылка №2</a>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">ссылка №3</a>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">ссылка №4</a>
    <div class="svg">
      <svg width="170mm" height="45mm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <g transform="translate(-1,-251.95859)">
           <path d="m1.00005 252.20983-1.511905 44.79017 170.46726-0.56696c-28.27272-4.30384-41.00151-28.7266-55.86311-34.64265-27.001632-10.74869-52.971732-10.13029-113.04224-9.58056z" fill="#b83d2e"/>
      </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Так же можно не выводить код svg в html и можно в этом случае сделать так :

```css
ul,
li,
a {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 480px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #b03023;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.svg {
  display: block;
  width: 164px;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='164.42mm' height='44.790192mm' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 164.42 44.790192' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg transform='translate(-2,-252.20981)'%3E%3Cpath d='M 164.42,296.811 C 108.15057,294.33073 97.997565,253.78942 62.744187,252.96577 L 0,252.20981 0.18899041,297 Z' fill='%23b03023'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Ссылка №1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Ссылка №2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Ссылка №3</a>
  </li>
  <div class="svg"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: все круто, только ему ещё требуется бекграунд градиентный наложить, а у вас появляется косяк если это сделать. http://icecream.me/67d1e71950cb45040aa509b08ca07336

Answer (score 6):

### Приложение полностью адаптивно.

### Работает во всех браузерах, включая *MS Edge*

Цвет, градиенты максимально приближены к оригиналу.

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.partBlack {
fill:url(#LGblack);
}
.partRed {
fill:url(#LGred);
}
.textRed {
font-size:72px;
fill:white;
}

.textBlack {
font-size:72px;
fill:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1388 868" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="LGred" x2="0%" y2="100%">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#C14A3A"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#A31D12"/>
 </linearGradient>  
       <linearGradient id="LGblack" x2="0%" y2="100%">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#444444"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#202020"/>
 </linearGradient> 
   </defs>
   <rect class="partBlack" x="4" y="260" width="1388" height="165"/>
   
   <path class="partRed"  d="M3.4 259.4H507.1c22.7 0 45.3 4.2 67.5 9.2 26.7 6 52.9 14.2 78.2 24.6 13.1 5.4 25.5 12.3 37.7 19.5 12.1 7.1 23.8 15.1 35.1 23.4 12.1 9 23.1 19.4 35.1 28.6 11.9 9 24 17.7 36.4 26 10.2 6.8 20.1 14.4 31.2 19.5 7.9 3.6 16.5 5.6 25 7.7 12.9 3.3 45.1 7.7 39.2 7.7L3.4 424.6Z" />  
   
    <text class="textRed" x="200" y="350" font-size="72px" fill="white">Контакты</text> 
   <text class="textBlack" x="850" y="350">тел.(650)5559462</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Я тут пожалуй минусану – отвратительное решение. С таким же успехом можно макет дизайнера вставить. То, что svg тянется как и любая другая картинка не делает решение адаптивным (кстати вы даже не сделали ее резиновой), адаптивности здесь нет и быть не может. Css в вашем решении вообще не нужен.

Answer (score 6):

### Решение №2 на чистом CSS

**Самое короткое настолько, насколько это возможно. Короче не придумаешь.**

**Полностью адаптивно на все 100%.**

**Работает во всех браузерах без исключений.**

```css
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.adaptive { margin-top: 15%; }
.nav__wrp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.nav__left, .nav__right {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
.nav__left { float: left; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred); }
.nav__right { float: right; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black); }
.nav__left:before, .nav__right:before, .nav__left:after, .nav__right:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 103%;
  top: 0;
}
.nav__left:before { right: 0; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black); }
.nav__right:before { left: 0; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred); }
.nav__left:after { right: -3%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, darkred); border-radius: 0 70% 0 0; }
.nav__right:after { left: -3%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, black); border-radius: 0 0 0 70%; }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
<div class="adaptive"></div>
<div class="nav__wrp"><div class="nav__left"></div><div class="nav__right"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Это можно сделать используя CSS?

### Да, можно.

Но лучше делать такое картинкой и подкладывать в нужное место через background-image или в виде элемента с абсолютным позиционированием. (например через псевдоэлемент before).

На CSS такое тоже можно сделать, но вы либо напишите пару страниц кода с border-radius, либо уйдете в полигоны/пути и SVG графику.

**Первое решение (чистый CSS)** - это ненужное награмождение и усложнение кода.

**Второе решение (clip-path + SVG)** - это по сути замена PNG картинки на SVG картинку (в конкретно вашем случае).

В огромном CSS, clip-path и SVG есть смысл только для создания красивых анимаций и переходов. (Ниже приложил пример правильного использования.)

### Хотите доказательств?

Опуститесь ниже и посмотрите другие варианты решения. Умные люди изощряются с ними и уже почти готовы друг друга на ножи посадить, выясняя чей CSS лучше.

А теперь представьте что Вам нужно не просто сделать такое, но и в дальнейшем обслуживать. Причем обслуживать будете не вы, а условный "Леха стажер", которого руководство нашло на фрилансе.

Желание блеснуть инструментарием подходит только для профессиональных сообществ вроде этого. В реальной разработке нужно использовать максимально простой вариант из решающих задачу. Это сокращает затраты, понижает порог вхождения в ваш проект, делает дальнейшее обслуживание удобным.

### Правильное применение css полигонов и SVG

Если интересно почитать про полигоны и их правильное применение в css, вот пример где использование этих инструментов оправдано:

[Создаем крутые фигуры с помощью Clip-Path и разбиваем привычную боксовую модель](https://medium.com/@Dimetrio89/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-clip-path-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-6f5d11ac9427)

Если интересно SVG и все что связано с его анимированием: 
https://svg-art.ru/

Создатель сайта тут сидит и регулярно дает ответы на вопросы. Профиль: [@Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt)

Comment: @Sevastopol' обновляю и улучшаю по мере развития топика, наглядно показывая почему нужно сделать по моему: `background-image:url(ссылка на картинку); внутри :before элемента` (автор знает как это сделать),а не всё что ниже. Ваш ответ и есть css на пару страниц (для просмотра требуется крутить пару экранов ползунок), ответ Q с аватаркой из киндзадза - это геометрия об которую сломаешь мозг (зато пара строчек). Вот и весь выбор для автора на чистом CSS. Сравните оба решения с `background-image`.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Кстати, я все решения в этом топике  комменднул (начиная с вашего), т.к. мне нравится изобретательность и профессионализм. Но ни одно из них в реальном проекте использовать не нужно.