# Как сделать плавную выпуклость?

Tags: html, css

Нужно повторить именно саму плавность выпуклости, а не просто вставить круглый псевдоэлемент

[image]

Comment: svg? быть может..

Comment: 3 круговых градиета.

Answer (score 7):

**Вариант на чистом CSS**

[Здесь можно найти множество других вариантов плавных переходов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1072628/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9), в том числе и [решения на CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1072946/31280).

```css
body {margin: 0; background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%); background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%); -webkit-background-size: 3px 3px; background-size: 3px 3px;}
.container {position: relative; width: 150px; height: 100vh; background-color: lightgray;}
.elem {display: block; position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; right: -30px; top: 50%; margin-top: -50px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: lightgray;}
.elem__t,.elem__b {overflow: hidden; position: absolute; padding: 40px 20px; width: 4px;}
.elem__t {top: 0%; right: 26px; margin-top: -40px; transform: rotate(-70deg);}
.elem__b {top: 0%; right: 26px; margin-top: 60px; transform: rotate(-108deg) scale(-1, 1);}
.elem__t-top,.elem__b-bottom {position: absolute; left: 100%; width: 400%; border-radius: 100%;}
.elem__t-top {top: 50%; box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px lightgray; transform: translate(-50%, 1%);}
.elem__b-bottom {top: 50%; box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px lightgray; transform: translate(-50%, 1%);}
.elem__t-top:before,.elem__b-bottom:before {content: ""; display: block;}
.elem__t-top:before {padding: 100% 0 1000px 0;}
.elem__b-bottom:before {padding: 100% 0 1000px 0;}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="elem"><div class="elem__t"><div class="elem__t-top"></div></div><div class="elem__b"><div class="elem__b-bottom"></div></div></div></div>
```

В качестве бонуса пример оживим, сделаем из него выдвижной блок:

```js
$('.elem').hover(function() {$('.container').addClass('container__hover');}, function() {$('.container').removeClass('container__hover');});
$('.elem').click(function() {$('.container').toggleClass('container__active');});
```

```css
body {margin: 0; background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%); background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%); -webkit-background-size: 3px 3px; background-size: 3px 3px;}
.container {position: relative; width: 1px; height: 100vh; background-color: lightgray; transition: width 0.25s ease-in-out;}
.elem {display: block; position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; right: -30px; top: 50%; margin-top: -50px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: lightgray; cursor: pointer;}
.elem__t,.elem__b {overflow: hidden; position: absolute; padding: 40px 20px; width: 4px;}
.elem__t {top: 0%; right: 26px; margin-top: -40px; transform: rotate(-70deg);}
.elem__b {top: 0%; right: 26px; margin-top: 60px; transform: rotate(-108deg) scale(-1, 1);}
.elem__t-top,.elem__b-bottom {position: absolute; left: 100%; width: 400%; border-radius: 100%;}
.elem__t-top {top: 50%; box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px lightgray; transform: translate(-50%, 1%);}
.elem__b-bottom {top: 50%; box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px lightgray; transform: translate(-50%, 1%);}
.elem__t-top:before,.elem__b-bottom:before {content: ""; display: block;}
.elem__t-top:before {padding: 100% 0 1000px 0;}
.elem__b-bottom:before {padding: 100% 0 1000px 0;}
.container__hover {width: 15px;}
.container__active {width: 50%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"><div class="elem"><div class="elem__t"><div class="elem__t-top"></div></div><div class="elem__b"><div class="elem__b-bottom"></div></div></div></div>
```

> тут меня вдруг осенило - а можно так сделать что бы эта выпуклость
>   появилась при hover ? – MaximLensky

Вариант с анимацией при наведении. Как говорится, любой каприз за ваши деньги :)

```js
$('.elem').hover(function() {$('.container').addClass('container__hover');}, function(){$('.container').removeClass('container__hover');});$('.elem').click(function() {$('.overlay').toggleClass('overlay__active');$('.container').toggleClass('container__active');$('.elem').toggleClass('elem__active');});
```

```css
body {margin: 0;  background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);  -webkit-background-size: 3px 3px;  background-size: 3px 3px;  z-index: 0;}
.container {position: relative;  width: 2px;  height: 100vh;  background-color: lightgray;  transition: width 0.25s ease-in-out;  z-index: 2;}
.container:before {content: "";  display: block;  position: absolute;  top: 0;  bottom: 0;  right: -30px;  width: 30px;}
.elem {display: block;  position: absolute;  width: 100px;  height: 100px;  right: -30px;  top: 50%;  margin-top: -50px;  border-radius: 100%;  background-color: lightgray;  cursor: pointer;  transform: scale(0);  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;}.elem__t,.elem__b {overflow: hidden;  position: absolute;  padding: 40px 20px;  width: 4px;}.elem__t {top: 0%;  right: 26px;  margin-top: -40px;  transform: rotate(-70deg);}.elem__b {top: 0%;  right: 26px;  margin-top: 60px;  transform: rotate(-108deg) scale(-1, 1);}.elem__t-top,.elem__b-bottom {position: absolute;  left: 100%;  width: 400%;  border-radius: 100%;}.elem__t-top {top: 50%;  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px lightgray;  transform: translate(-50%, 1%);}.elem__b-bottom {top: 50%;  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px lightgray;  transform: translate(-50%, 1%);}.elem__t-top:before,.elem__b-bottom:before {content: "";  display: block;}.elem__t-top:before {padding: 100% 0 1000px 0;}.elem__b-bottom:before {padding: 100% 0 1000px 0;}.container__hover {width: 15px;}.container__active {width: 50%;  box-shadow: 5px 0px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.1);  animation-name: Open;  animation-duration: 1.5s;  animation-iteration-count: 1;  animation-direction: normal;}@keyframes Open {from {    width: 2px;  }  50% {    width: 60%;  }  to {    width: 50%;  }}.overlay__active {position: fixed;  top: 0;  left: 0;  right: 0;  bottom: 0;  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);  z-index: -1;  animation-name: Overlay;  animation-duration: 1.5s;  animation-iteration-count: 1;  animation-direction: normal;}@keyframes Overlay {  from {    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);  }  to {    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);  }}
.container:hover .elem {transform: scale(1);}.elem__active {transform: scale(1)!important;  box-shadow: 10px 0px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.1);}
span {position: absolute;  top: 50%;  margin-top: -8px;  left: 49px;  font-size: 14px;  color: gray;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>&larr; наведи</span><div class="container"><div class="elem"><div class="elem__t"><div class="elem__t-top"></div></div><div class="elem__b"><div class="elem__b-bottom"></div></div></div></div><div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: нормально, с меня + (только чуток кривовато, можно довести)

Comment: @Sevastopol', у меня хоть и не глаз-алмаз, но, вроде как, верхняя часть более выпуклая, чем нижняя (если вертикально смотреть)

Comment: @Sevastopol', видимо мы неправильно друг друга поняла) выпоклость-то ладно, но она чуть кривовата, она ведь явно должна быть равномерная, разве нет?) О, а щас нормально)

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле, для svg эта форма - не сложная, описывается двумя кривыми Безье, координаты для которых очень просто вычислить в уме или на бумаге:

```html
<svg width=300 height=300>
  <path d="
m 0 0
h 125
v 50
c 0 50  50 50  50 100
c 0 50 -50 50 -50 100
v 50
h -125
  " /></svg>
```

Как видите, одна команда “c” сопровождается 3 мя точками, первые 2 из них - контрольные точки кривой Безье, а третья - конечная точка, если все эти точки нарисовать - получится очень незамысловатая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg viewbox="-50 -10 150 150" height=100vh>

  <circle r=3 cx=0 cy=0 />
  <circle r=3 cx=0 cy=50 />
  <circle r=3 cx=50 cy=50 />
  <circle r=3 cx=50 cy=100 />

  <path d="
m 0 0
c 0 50 50 50 50 100
  " stroke=red fill=none />
  
  </svg>
```

BONUS:

```js
let dir = -1, p = 0;

let elastic = t => Math.pow(2,-10*t) * 
                   Math.sin((t-0.2/4)*(2*Math.PI)/0.2) + 1
                   
addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let r = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  let dx = e.x - r.x - r.width/2;
  let dy = e.y - r.y - r.height/2;
  dir = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) > 50 ? -1 : 1;
});

function draw(t) {
  p = Math.max(0, Math.min(p+(dir>0?0.02:-0.1), 1));
  let pt = (dir>0?elastic(p):Math.sqrt(p))*25;
  path.setAttribute('d', `m 0 0 h 125 v 25
    c 0 30  ${pt} 30  ${pt} 60
    c 0 30 -${pt} 30 -${pt} 60
    v 25 h -125`)
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<svg id=svg width=250 height=170><path id=path /></svg>
```

Comment: так же есть вот такой вариант развития событий https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/GRgLMwy

Answer (score 4):

Изначально, если какой то объект в svg сложнее чем можно сделать руками то рисуют уже в графическом редакторе как и я в этом примере, открыл inkscape и дальше скрины по шагам

1) Выбирает инструмент `Рисовать прямоугольники и квадраты` на панеле инструментов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Потом в меню программы находим `Контур` и нажимает `Оконтурить объект`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Выбираем инструмент `Редактировать узлы контуром и рычаги контуров` и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) ставим точки и выравниваем как душе угодно но согласно макета у меня получилось вот это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5) Выдеяем эти три точки и нажмём на дополнительном меню программы на `Сделать выделенные узлы автоматически сглаженными`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6) Выравниваем лишнее инструментом из третьего пункта и получаем вот это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Последнее : Сохраняем как простой svg чистим от не нужного и пользуемся кодом - превью в снипете

```css
.item{
  height: 100vh;
}

.item svg{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <svg  viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="m0 0.66666663h83.910713s-2.882957 72.709545 4.264202 108.03266c3.315168 16.38442 17.307115 30.22482 17.658415 46.93757 0.36654 17.43751-13.077122 32.57246-16.349987 49.70399-5.83825 30.55981-5.57263 93.17099-5.57263 93.17099h-83.910713z" fill="#666"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```